# Add Piecemaker to Wordpress Header

Tags: plugins

I wish to add the Piecemaker 3D rotator to Wordpress theme TwentyEleven In Header and NOT as a POST or Page. Via Wordpress Plugin: Piecemaker 2

Steps:
 1. Piecemaker Created with Assets
 2. Tested on POST/PAGE. Getting displayed correctly.

Question:

1. How to display it in Header instead Of the TwentyEleven images
   (Header script removed)

What should i do to display the Piecemaker in Header.

I have tried:

1. Adding below code in Functions.php Source: Support forums

   ```
   /**
    * Function to use piece maker outside post content
    *
    **/
   function display_piecemaker($att = null){
   global $pm;

   if(!is_array($att)){
       $att = array(
           'id' => $att,
       );
   }

        echo $pm->replaceBooks($att);
   }
   ```
2. Calling the function in theme file:

   ```
   <?php if( is_home() ) {
   display_piecemaker(array('id' => 1));
   }?>
   ```

Note: I am beginner with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this working in the passed using the shortcode
place this in your header:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[piecemaker id="1"]'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot [Bainternet](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2487/bainternet).



This has resolved the issue.

Just wondering how should we disable this flash display for mobile devices.

Comment: That should be a different question